# pass a variable increasing by Number

Tags: php, ajax

I have a variable that increases when I choose Number of persons, so I want to pass this variable by ajax to another page.

my code is like:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  container.append('<tr><th width="120"><div align="left">Person on Room "'+i+'"</div></th><td><input type="text" name="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle'+i+'[]" id="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle'+i+'" size="15" placeholder="Single Room"></td></tr>');
}
```

How can I define this `name="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle'+i+'[]"` by ajax to passing to another page php.

I will try this but it send me error, which a good way to define variable.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
  var txtHotelCustomerNameSingle+i = $('#withHotel').serialize();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Array` is a better solution.

```
var txtHotelCustomerNameSingle = new Array();
for (...)
{
    txtHotelCustomerNameSingle[i] = ...
}
```

Comment: Or you could just do `var txtHotelCustomerNameSingle = []; for(...`

Comment: ok, but how can i distinct this `<input type="text" name="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle1[]" id="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle1" size="15" placeholder="Single Room">` and this `<input type="text" name="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle2[]" id="txtHotelCustomerNameSingle2" size="15" placeholder="Single Room"> `

Comment: put same name in your inputs and when your form will be send datas, it will be send inputs (with the same name) as array